# Removing partition by reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

My laptop was running on Windows XP. Then I decided to try Ubuntu. (It's fast and sleek, btw) I chose the dual-boot option. Days later, I decided to fully commit to the latter.

At first, I tried to reinstall Ubuntu by running the USB installer, but the action won't work. Then, after searching for some help, I formatted the Windows partition (almost 75% of the HDD). Next was to expand Ubuntu to the formatted partition.

Now here's the complication: it can't, and I don't know what to do. I'm still trying to reinstall it, even resorted to downgrading, of no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Use GParted. Install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Screenshot from GParted site:
[image]

Delete old Windows partition by right clicking on it and selecting `delete` and then right click ubuntu partition and choose `resize/move`.

Answer (score 1):

This method is re-installing the system (backup important data but it seems there is none yet). If you want to keep the current system follow Cornelius method (though a reinstall might be quicker ;) ).

- Insert the Ubuntu DVD or the USB into your system
- Reboot with the DVD or USB as 1st boot device.
- Wait for it to load and show:

[image]

- Choose Install.
- Insert all data and press continue until you reach the partitioning.
- Choose: "something else" if you want ALL current operating systems deleted.
- Delete all the partitions (select partition and choose the - on the left side).
- Create new partitions. You must create 1 with name /. 15 Gb can be enough. A basic setup can also have a swap (2x the amount of memory if under 8G. More: 8Gb can be enough), and /home for the remaining Gbs.
- Continue and fill out the other question.

Result should be a working desktop with only Ubuntu installed.

After that update system, pick a video driver if needed and start installing software you want.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer from CD/DVD/USB, when you see the screen for installing alongside or instead of.. Windows XP/Ubuntu choose "Other". There is partition manager.